# Can I bind a type to a primitive representation (string, number) with Embind?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten, embind

I am learning Emscripten and Embind. I have written some bindings for my types, but for all of them I receive a complex object on javascript side that must be deleted using `delete()`.

For some things, I would prefer to avoid that. Specifically, I have two types:

- Custom string type that has fixed max length, backed by `std::array<char>`
- Custom number wrapper that protects against conversion to unrelated numbers, has only one member which is the underlying value

Example concept:

```
// my_number_value.h
struct my_number_value
{
  explicit my_number_value(int x) : x{x} {}
  int x;
}
```

So now I can write binding like this:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include "my_number_value.h"

#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

struct my_number_value_helper
{
  static emscripten::val getValue(
    const my_number_value& v)
  {
    return emscripten::val(v.x);
  }
};

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE my_number_value getNumber()
{
  return my_number_value{42};
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(mymodule)
{
class_<my_number_value>("my_number_value")
    .property("x", &my_number_value_helper::getValue)
    ;
function("getNumber", &getNumber);
}
#endif
```

Then in JS, if I have a function that returns that value type, I have to do:

```
function getNumber() {
    const num = Module.getNumber();
    const val = num.x;
    num.delete();
    return val;
}
```

My question here is how to instead tell emscripten to convert this type from and to ordinary number, so that `Module.getNumber()` returns `number` and similarly passing a `number` to a function that expects `my_number_value` will create new `my_number_value` on the c++ side on stack.

Since I use these a lot, it would be much more practical than writing a wrapper for every method or function that uses this type. Same for my string type. Embind does automatically convert `std::string` to javascript `string`, so I'd like the same for my custom string.

Even better would be if I also could register all enums to convert to string (I already have functions to convert enums from string and back).